# Failed to connect to containerd

Tags: docker

I ran a command like this in a docker-in-docker (dind) scenario:

```
docker daemon --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 --storage-driver=overlay
```

And I got this in the logs:

```
INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 18
FATA[0000] Failed to connect to containerd. Please make sure containerd is installed in your PATH or you have specificed the correct address. Got error: write /proc/18/oom_score_adj: permission denied
```

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to run the container in `privileged` mode.

```
docker run --privileged ...
```

This should fix the problem; you should now be able to install and run Docker inside this Docker image.

Comment: But you were trying to run dockerd right? what has docker run got to do with this? How did you solve the error related to containerd?

Comment: @MaheshM Apparently this refers to the "outer" docker within which the OP is trying to run another Docker.